# Looping through Pandas dataframes by addressing those with a variable

Tags: python, loops, pandas, variables, dataframe

I am trying to do a set of repetitive operations on a set of similar dataframes (in this example, converting strings of timestamps to datetime objects).
My original dataframe:

```
     Date_assetA  assetA    Date_assetB  assetB    Date_assetC  assetC  \
0  06/09/16 8:00  4629.0  06/09/16 5:50   208.2  06/09/16 5:50  209.05   
1  06/09/16 8:10  4629.5  06/09/16 6:00   208.0  06/09/16 6:00  208.85   
2  06/09/16 8:20  4630.0  06/09/16 6:10   208.1  06/09/16 6:10  208.95   
3  06/09/16 8:30  4632.5  06/09/16 6:20   208.1  06/09/16 6:20  208.95   
4  06/09/16 8:40  4630.5  06/09/16 6:30   208.1  06/09/16 6:30  208.95   

   Date_assetD  assetD  
0  06/09/16 5:50  209.70  
1  06/09/16 6:00  209.50  
2  06/09/16 6:10  209.60  
3  06/09/16 6:50  209.55  
4  06/09/16 7:10  209.65
```

I build four independant DataFrames from the initial one, as i will need to align those after converting the Date_assetX columns to timestamps. I want to loop through those by adressing them using the list of assets. Here is my code, with the missing part. Any attempt as concatenating a name of df_assetX failed so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

df_assetA = df[['Date_assetA', 'assetA']]
df_assetB = df[['Date_assetB', 'assetB']]
df_assetC = df[['Date_assetC', 'assetC']]
df_assetD = df[['Date_assetD', 'assetD']]

contract_list = ['assetA', 'assetB', 'assetC', 'assetD']
for contract in contract_list:
    date_column = 'Date_' + str(contract)
    df_contract = # That's the part where i'm stuck...
    df_contract.date_column = pd.to_datetime(df_contract.date_column, dayfirst=True)
```

Is there something obvious i'm missing, or is the whole approach botched  and i should try the dictionary route instead ?

Thanks,

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to concatenate but why not parse date columns in the original df?

Comment: @gereleth, I want to loop through the the list of contracts, and for each <contract>, work on the df named df_<contract> and the its columns Date_<contract>.

Answer (score 0):

I used a dictionary instead. Surely this code can be improved to build the dictionary using loops, but for my current needs, it'll cut it for now.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

df_assetA = df[['Date_assetA', 'assetA']]
df_assetB = df[['Date_assetB', 'assetB']]
df_assetC = df[['Date_assetC', 'assetC']]
df_assetD = df[['Date_assetD', 'assetD']]

dico = {'assetA':df_assetA, 
        'assetB':df_assetB, 
        'assetC':df_assetC, 
        'assetD':df_assetD}

for contract, df_contract in dico.items():
    Date_contract = 'Date_' + contract
    df_contract[Date_contract] = pd.to_datetime(df_contract[Date_contract], dayfirst=True)
    print df_contract.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is do create a list of dataframes, then concat them all at once. It would look something like this:

```
Frames = []
# Start the loop
for contract in contract_list:
    df = ... # Do whatever
    Frames.append(df)
# Concat
All = pd.concat(Frames)
```